# Error : C5.0 models require a factor outcome

Tags: r, machine-learning

i have data which look like this:

```
     IntensityRisk Depth  Mag  smaj  smin
           <fctr> <int>  <int> <int> <int>
 1             2     2     3     2     2
 2             3     1     3     2     2
 3             3     1     3     2     2
 4             3     1     1     2     2
 5             3     1     1     2     2
 6             2     2     3     2     2
 7             3     1     3     2     2
 8             3     1     3     2     2
 9             3     1     3     2     2
10             2     2     3     2     2
```

I made this following steps:

```
gempaDF <- gempa[order(runif(nrow(gempa))),]
str(gempaDF$IntensityRisk)
tail(gempaDF,5)
gempaTrain <- gempaDF[1:4000,]
gempaTest <- gempaDF[4001:4471,]
C50_model <- C5.0(gempaTrain[,-1], gempaTrain[,1])
```

and getting error like this:

```
Error in C5.0.default(gempaTrain[, -1], gempaTrain[, 1]) : 
  C5.0 models require a factor outcome
```

i have changed it to this:

```
C50_model <- C5.0(gempaTrain[,-1], gempaTrain[,as.factor(gempaDF$IntensityRisk)])
```

and getting error again:

```
Error: Unsupported index type: factor
```

Then i try changing it to this:

```
gempaDF <- gempa[order(runif(nrow(gempa))),]
gempaDF$IntensityRisk <- as.factor(gempaDF$IntensityRisk)
str(gempaDF$IntensityRisk)
tail(gempaDF,5)
gempaTrain <- gempaDF[1:4000,]
gempaTest <- gempaDF[4001:4471,]
C50_model <- C5.0(gempaTrain[,-1], gempaTrain[,1])
```

But still getting error like this:

```
Error in C5.0.default(gempaTrain[, -1], gempaTrain[, 1]) : 
  C5.0 models require a factor outcome
```

I'm trying this too:

```
C50_model <- C5.0(gempaTrain[,-1], gempaTrain[,gempaDF$IntensityRisk])
```

But still getting error

```
Error: Unsupported index type: factor
```

Does anyone know where i did wrong? I appreciate it so much.

Comment: `gempaTrain[,as.factor(gempaDF$IntensityRisk)]` doesn't work because R is expecting one or more numerical values in the column index slot, but `as.factor(gempaDF$IntensityRisk)` returns a vector of category values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the following sample data (as I don't have access to your data)

```
set.seed(1)
dat = tibble::as_tibble(list(IntensityRisk = sample(1:5, 30, replace = T), Depth = sample(1:100, 30, replace = T), Mag = sample(1:100, 30, replace = T)))

table(dat$IntensityRisk)
 1  2  3  4  5 
 4 11  2  7  6 


# convert the response to factor,

dat$IntensityRisk = as.factor(dat$IntensityRisk)

str(dat)

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ IntensityRisk: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 3 5 2 5 5 4 4 1 ...
 $ Depth        : int  49 60 50 19 83 67 80 11 73 42 ...
 $ Mag          : int  92 30 46 34 66 26 48 77 9 88 ...
```

If I use the tibble dataframe I get a similar error,

```
fit = C50::C5.0(dat1[, -1], dat1[, 1])

Error in C5.0.default(dat[, -1], dat[, 1]) : 
  C5.0 models require a factor outcome
```

If I convert to a dataframe,

```
dat1 = as.data.frame(dat)

str(dat1)

'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ IntensityRisk: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 3 5 2 5 5 4 4 1 ...
 $ Depth        : int  49 60 50 19 83 67 80 11 73 42 ...
 $ Mag          : int  92 30 46 34 66 26 48 77 9 88 ...
```

the function runs error free,

```
fit = C50::C5.0(dat1[, -1], dat1[, 1])

> fit

Call:
C5.0.default(x = dat1[, -1], y = dat1[, 1])

Classification Tree
Number of samples: 30 
Number of predictors: 2 

Tree size: 8 

Non-standard options: attempt to group attributes
```